# There's no order number when provision VM by SL API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

There's order number when I provision VM by APIs for SL account 1473995. This is one VM provisioned by API: https://control.softlayer.com/devices/details/50115597/virtualGuest

Since I can provision VM in control portal and got an order number.

Is there any different between API call with portal? Since the API can can't get order number now (It worked fine at Feb 3th).

Can anyone help to have a look at the account parameter, if it needs manually steps for api call provision VMs?

This is part of my code:

```
service := services.GetVirtualGuestService(sess)

// Create a Virtual_Guest instance as a template
vGuestTemplate := datatypes.Virtual_Guest{
Hostname: sl.String(spec.HostName),
Domain: sl.String(spec.Domain),
MaxMemory: sl.Int(spec.Memory),
StartCpus: sl.Int(spec.CPUs),
Datacenter: &datatypes.Location{Name: sl.String(spec.DataCenter)}, // Dal 12
OperatingSystemReferenceCode: sl.String(spec.OperatiingSystem), // UBUNTU_LATEST
LocalDiskFlag: sl.Bool(true),
HourlyBillingFlag: sl.Bool(true),
PrivateNetworkOnlyFlag: sl.Bool(true),
SshKeys: sshkeys,   
PrimaryBackendNetworkComponent: &datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Network_Component{NetworkVlan: &datatypes.Network_Vlan{Id: sl.Int(spec.VlanID)}, // VlanID is 2177691
},  
}

vGuest, err := service.Mask("id;domain").CreateObject(&vGuestTemplate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [createObject](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject) method never returns the orderId, the differnce with the portal is that the portal uses the [placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/) method which is more complex than the createObject method:

here you can see some explanation about the use of the placeOrder method:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3

Now it is possible to get the orderId from the VM using object mask here an RESTFul example for that:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VMID/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,billingItem[id,orderItem[id,order]]]
```

Just replace $VMID with the id that the create object method returned or also you can use globalId which is also returned by the createObject method, notice that the VM order needs to be approved if it is not apporved yet the request will not work.

As you are using the GO client you just need to translate the request above.

Comment: Yes I used the Go lang client. The code works before. Actually I don't need the Order. Because the api call provisioned VMs have no order caused it stop to do other transactions and hang at there.  And some from the sales support team told me that it needs manually steps to create order.

Comment: It works well before our vacation. But it doesn't work now. I don't the exactly time.

Comment: What I see this is an issue with Softlayer, its provisioning process is doing something wrong and it does not have anything to do with the API call because the order has been processed (otherwise you will get an error when calling the API)  I recommend you to submit an ticket in the portal about this error.